# make bootstrap 4 display flex child divs width 100% in xs screen mode

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm using flex on divs containing meta data in my header of my product page.

I ideally don't wan't to convert my current code to columns because the beauty of flex is that it flexes to the content, rather than restricting the content.

This is my current code below...

```
<div class="h6 d-flex" id="product_meta">

   <div class="order-sm-0 order-1" style="background:red;">
       Some categorys - tags - etc
   </div>

   <div class="ml-sm-auto text-sm-right order-sm-1 order-0 mb-sm-0 mb-1" style="background:cyan;">
       SKU #000000 - From £2.55
   </div>       

</div>
```

Full demo here: https://www.codeply.com/go/PKYh4oHvTC

If you look at my screenshot below in **Small Screen** and up mode, I am using `ml-sm-auto` to push the right meta away from the left meta. This is great because pretty much any content can run fluid to the max capacity.

[image]

The problem I have, is that in **Extra Small Screen** mode I need to reverse the order of the meta divs, so the SKU appears first, and make both divs 100% width.

In **Extra Small Screen** mode, the reversing order is currently working fine. But I cant make the divs width 100%.

See mocked screenshot below of how I need it to look in **Extra Small Screen** mode.

[image]

As you can see in my mocked screenshot above, the order is reversed and the divs are fullwidth.

But I cannot seem to recreate this in my code, `width: 100%;` does not effect divs in the normal block way when using `.d-flex` in the parent div.

Can anyone advise?

https://www.codeply.com/go/PKYh4oHvTC

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code below ended sorting the problem I had, using `.flex-column` in mobile and `.flex-sm-grow` in small screen and and above.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<main class="container">
  <div id="product_header">

    <h1 class="h2">This is my product title heading</h1>
    <hr/>
    <div class="h6 d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row" id="product_meta">
      <div class="order-sm-0 order-1" style="background:red;">
        Some categorys - tags - etc
      </div>
      <div class="text-sm-right order-sm-1 order-0 flex-grow-1 mb-sm-0 mb-1" style="background:cyan;">
        SKU #000000 - From £2.55
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Appreciate your help yesterday